# Deep Reinforcement Learning

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am new in this field and I am trying to understand the Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient (DDPG) model. I can not understand the use of the target network in this model. Why do we need to define the target network for actor-network and critic-network?